# How to backtrace in a maze...?

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion, maze

So I'm writing a program to make a robot explore a maze to find a specified cavern. There are four types of Cells: Cavern, Start, Wall, and Passage. Robots can only move to a passage or a cavern. I implemented my method so that a robot can't move to a visited cell or go out of bounds. But once it moves to a cell where there isn't a valid adjacent cell, the program stops. So how do I make my robot backtrace to where  there is a valid cell? I'm using a recursion for this. Below is my code. Any help will be great. Thank you!

```
public void explore (Cell cavern, Maze maze) throws InterruptedException {
    // for debugging
    System.out.println(row + " " + col);
    System.out.println(cavern.getRow() + " " + cavern.getCol());
    System.out.println(visited.toString());
     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10); // delay program
    //base case
    if (row == cavern.getRow() && col == cavern.getCol()) {
        foundCavern = true;
        return;
    }
    else {
        // move right
        if ((col+1) < maze.getNumCols() && !visited.contains(maze.getCell(row, col+1)) && (maze.getCell(row, col+1).isPassage() || maze.getCell(row, col+1).isCavern())) {
            visited.add(maze.getCell(row, col+1));
            setRobotLocation(row,col+1);
            explore(cavern, maze);
        }
        // move down
        else if ((row+1) < maze.getNumRows() && !visited.contains(maze.getCell(row+1, col)) && (maze.getCell(row+1, col).isPassage() || maze.getCell(row+1, col).isCavern())) {
            visited.add(maze.getCell(row+1, col));
            setRobotLocation(row+1,col);
            explore(cavern, maze);
        }
        // move left
        else if ((col-1) >= 0 && !visited.contains(maze.getCell(row, col-1)) && (maze.getCell(row, col-1).isPassage() || maze.getCell(row, col-1).isCavern())) {
            visited.add(maze.getCell(row, col-1));
            setRobotLocation(row,col-1);
            explore(cavern, maze);
        }
        // move up
        else if ((row-1) >= 0 && !visited.contains(maze.getCell(row-1, col)) && (maze.getCell(row-1, col).isPassage() || maze.getCell(row-1, col).isCavern())) {
            visited.add(maze.getCell(row-1, col));
            setRobotLocation(row-1,col);
            explore(cavern, maze);
        }
        else {
            foundCavern = false;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using recursion, it might be simpler to just keep the moves you've made in a stack.

Comment: So my visited list should be a stack then? I kind of get why but can you give me some more details. Like, where should I pop in my code?

Comment: I think you should get rid of the `else` and instead check if you also need to continue to other directions meaning when you get back from an `explore` call you still haven't found the cavern

Comment: Any time you make a move you haven't made before, you push its location on the stack.  Then to retrace your steps, you just pop the last location off and move there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in the right direction.
What I think you should do is keep checking for all direction unless you found the cavern.
Right now you are checking for only one direction in each iteration because of the `else` clause. So when the call to `explore` returns you can't keep checking a different direction and essentially you don't backtrack.
If you make your `explore` function return a `Boolean` field indicating whether you reached the cavern changing your code like this may work:

```
// move right
if ... // your condition to check if moving right is possible and you didn't visit
// code to move right
found = explore()
//move down if didn't find cavern
if (!found) // and moving down is possible and didn't visit
// code to move down
found = explore()
// keep checking other directions
```

Comment: That makes so much sense! Ill try that when I'm at my laptop and ill let u know how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: That actually didn't work for me. But I did get it to work. I just had to save the robot's location before all of the if statements and restoring the location after each if statement. Thanks for all the help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Right I missed the statement to revert the location when explore returns. Does it work with the `else` though? Or did you have to remove it like I suggested?

Comment: I did remove the `else` statement. I initialized foundCavern to false (outside the function) so didn't have to set it to false when robot doesn't find the cavern. And I did change all the `else if` to just `if`. Or else, it would have skipped all the other `else if` when it returns, just like you said. Thanks for the help. Really helped.